# Coefficients of power series

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

After expansion, we have
$$
(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n)^m=a_1x_1^m+a_2x_1^{m-1}x_2+\dots
$$
where $x_{()}$ is the variable and constant indices $n>m$.

> What is the expressions of all these possible coefficients $a_{()}$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is given by the "multinomial theorem", an extension of the binomial theorem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem.

Comment: Thanks for your reference. It does help!